# Null Reference Exception from Gridview DataKey

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, oledb

With this site, I am attempting to insert a row in a database through a selection on a gridview row.  I've got everything working well except for collecting the primary key from the gridview.  I've tried all I can find to no avail.  I'm not great with this language as of yet, but my code is below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sdsMicrosoftDB"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection currentConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    string eventID = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    try
    {
        string eid = Session["eid"].ToString();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblVolunteerRoster (eventID,empID) VALUES (@eventID,@empID)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = currentConnection;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventID", eventID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", eid);
        currentConnection.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

The code specific to that gridview is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="eventID" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" DataField="eventID" 
                        HeaderText="Event ID" SortExpression="eventID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="eventStartDate" HeaderText="Start Date" 
                        SortExpression="eventStartDate" DataFormatString="{0:MMM dd yyyy}" 
                        ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="eventDescription" HeaderText="Description" 
                        SortExpression="eventDescription" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="eventEstHours" HeaderText="Est. Hours" 
                        SortExpression="eventEstHours" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="eventLocation" HeaderText="Location" 
                        SortExpression="eventLocation" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="eventWorkersNeeded" HeaderText="Workers Needed" 
                        SortExpression="eventWorkersNeeded" />
              </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

Any ideas?  I've beat my head against a wall trying to figure it out on my own.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect, what happens, what have you tried? Show the exact error message and the line it occurs on.

Comment: You have to handler `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of `RowCommand` to return key value using `GridView1.SelectedValue` property.

Comment: I am receiving a null reference error on the line that reads:
string eventID = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString(); (first code block, line 6)

I am wanting this to pull the event ID from the row of the GridView I click 'Select' on, but all it does is throw this error.  Previous attempts have resulted in values of -1, which my access database won't allow due to referential integrity.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the datakeyname

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
string eventID = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Changing to SelectedIndexChanged instead of RowCommand did the trick.  Thanks, AVD!